# Best practice for class declaration in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a certain amount of experience in object oriented languages but I'm a total beginner in C++ and I'm wondering what is the best way to write a class in C++, especially since you have two types of files.

At the moment, all my class is in the header files, should I just leave my attributes and function definitions in the header files and then implement them in the cpp file?

my current Keyboard.h :

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Element.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Keyboard : public Element
{
private :
    std::vector<std::string> m_creators;
    std::vector<std::string> m_seller;
    int m_yearOfCreation;

public : 
    Keyboard(std::string& _name, std::vector<std::string>& _creators, std::vector<std::string> _seller, int _yearOfCreation) : Element(_name)
    {
        m_creators = _creators;
        m_seller = _seller;
        m_yearOfCreation = _yearOfCreation;
    }
    void Etat()
    {
        std::cout << "Dunno";
    }


};
```

Also I see many people writing the function signature in the class and then defining it externally with :: I don't really understand the interest to do that :/

Comment: You have only a prototype in the class body so to clean up it for a reader who is concerned only with the interface to your class. The definitions go after, for those who need to know internals of the class.

Comment: The reason to separate out interface / declaration in the header files, and implementation / definition in the source files, is to help project compile times by reducing incremental recompiles of most-or-all the project merely because an implementation changed.  Small projects, not so important.  Big projects, very important.  C++20 modules may make the long time practice irrelevant.

Comment: First of all you need to learn the distinction between a *declaration* and a *definition*. A declaration is telling the compiler that the thing exists somewhere in your program. A definition is the thing itself. For a function you can declare it in the header file, and define (implement) it in a source file. And there's really no "best" practice about this separation, it's left up to what you feel like doing. Although large functions are seldom put in header files.

Comment: Okay I understand better, what about the external definitions with ::? What is the use of doing this ?

Comment: BTW, missing some const, better to use initialization member list instead of assignation in constructor body.

Comment: @Jarod42 You would have an example, I don't really know what you mean

Comment: `Keyboard(const std::string& _name, const std::vector<std::string>& _creators /*, ..*/) : Element(_name), m_creators(_creators) /*, ..*/ {/*Empty*/}`. `void Etat() const`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - What you say is correct.   You have omitted the fact that a definition is a type of declaration   (i.e. all definitions are declarations, not all declarations are definitions).